# How to prove this for a self-complementary graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I couldn't understand how to prove that a self-complementary graph could only have 4n or 4n+1 vertices with n being a positive integer.

Comment: Hint: If $G$ is a self-complementary graph on $n$ vertices, then the complete graph $K_n$ must have an even number of edges.

Answer (score 1):

If a graph $ G $ is self-complimentary with $ k $ vertices then its complement $ G' $ must of course have the same number of edges. Sticking $ G $ and $ G' $ together will give us the complete graph on $ k $ vertices, which has $ {k \choose 2} $ edges. Hence G has $ \frac{1}{2} {k \choose 2} = \frac{k(k-1)}{4} $ edges.